# Cross-browser showModalDialog Replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So we have an internal web app that was written back in the IE6 days that we are trying to get to a state where it will work cross-browser, including mobile devices. We are using ASP.NET and the codebehind is written in VB.NET.

Unfortunately the app uses the showModalDialog function that only really works in Internet Explorer (and sort of in Firefox) all over the place. It also makes use of the window.returnValue from these popups, so what it expects is that when PopUpWindow() is called, the javascript would block on that statement and stop execution. Most calls are of the form "var a = PopUpWindow(..)". Then when the popup is closed, it would resume and set a to the returnValue and then make use of it.

It looks like these days javascript doesn't really do blocking function calls, which is making the process of finding an easy cross-browser replacement frustrating. We have a javascript file that is included on every page that contains the function that opens the popup windows. We would ideally like to replace this function in this file and have it work across the application without having to make changes on every single page where there is a popup.

Is there anything that would help with this or is there a standard way of replacing these kinds of dialog popups? We are looking at replacing them with jQuery dialogs but since we would need to use a callback function to get the returnValue it wouldn't work as a drop-in replacement. I'm getting the feeling that there is no easy way to do this (since our code relies on blocking javascript) and we will have to bite the bullet and make the changes to each page with a popup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [showModalDialog polyfill](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog) using a modal `<dialog>` element, which works in the latest Google Chrome. For other browsers, a [`<dialog>` polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill) is available.